# Using the initials for citing the authors after the first cite

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite, bibliographystyle

I have a text that makes constantly a reference to some authors. My idea is that only the first cite shows the complete names and after this I only want to show the initials. I though to use

```
\bibliographystyle{alphanum}
```

but all the references change.

`Finally, other authors apply the \cite{Diebold2009, Diebold2012}, hereafter DY, methodology based on the decomposition of the forecast error variance using a Vector Autorregressive (VAR) model.`

My idea is that after this citation when I use `\cite` or `\citep` the text does not cite

> Diebold and Yilmaz (2009, 2012)

but

> DY (2009, 2012)

Thanks for the help